# App to test WiFi signal strength

Tags: apps, wifi

I'm looking for a way to map my network dead spots. Are there any marketplace apps that display a signal strength meter to assist in something like this? I've looked at TestMyNet but it only seems to scan one time on demand, it's not really a meter. I'm basically looking for Android's **WiFi Analyzer** for Windows Phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current SDK does not allow that type of access. Sorry, but there is no app for it, and I am pretty sure no homebrew app exists either.

Answer (score 3):

The only place I can see WiFi strength is in the WiFi Settings. Where you can see every WiFi network and the signal strength.

**EDIT**

With the introduction of Windows Phone 8.1 you can see the strength right there near the carrier signal.

Comment: This is correct, if you have CYAN or later installed with Windows Phone 8.1, you will see WiFi signal strength along with signal transmission icons.

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy I don't think CYAN is needed. I think HTC shows this too. I'm wrong? Because I really don't remember. I do remember that CYAN is needed to show those arrows above the signal.

Comment: You're correct, here is the official docs for the icons. It mentions the exact version you need to see the arrows http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/calling-and-messaging/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean